Why are my Ray-Triangle intersection tests failing and causing gaps in model?
I am writing a ray tracer in java and have tried to implement a BVH, since implementing it I have been encountering white gaps in my model that indicate that triangles that should be there are not passing the intersection tests. I will attach some code below.
this is my render function
public void render(BVHNode bvhRoot) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 1000; column++) {
                Vector pixelSceneVector = new Vector(camPos.x + row, camPos.y - column, camPos.z);
                Ray ray = new Ray(pixelSceneVector, viewDir);
                IntersectionInfo intersectionInfo = bvhRoot.traverse(ray);
                if (intersectionInfo != null) {
                    Vector lightRay = lightSrc.sub(intersectionInfo.getIntersectionPoint());
                    lightRay.normalise();
                    Vector normal = intersectionInfo.getNormal();
                    normal.normalise();
                    double lightScalar = normal.dot(lightRay);
                    if (Math.abs(lightScalar) < 0.15) {
                        writer.setColor(row,column,Color.color(0,0,0));
                    } else {
                        writer.setColor(row,column,Color.color(0.8 * Math.abs(lightScalar),0.2 * Math.abs(lightScalar),0.3 * Math.abs(lightScalar)));
                    }
                } else {
                    writer.setColor(row,column, Color.color(1,1,1));
                }
            }
        }
    }

The traversal function which is called in "IntersectionInfo intersectionInfo = bvhRoot.traverse(ray);" runs a method called intersect in my Triangle class which is here
public IntersectionInfo intersect(Ray ray) {
        double EPSILON = 0.00001;

        Vector viewDir = ray.getDirection();
        Vector pixelSceneVector = ray.getOrigin();

        Vector normal = getNormal();
        double normalDotViewDir = normal.dot(viewDir);

        // Check if the triangle is facing away from the ray
        double normalDotRayDir = getNormal().dot(ray.getDirection());
        if (normalDotRayDir > 0) {
            // Triangle is facing away from the ray (backface), skip intersection
            return null;
        }

        //double k = normal.dot(accessVertices(1).getPos().sub(pixelSceneVector)) / normalDotViewDir;
        double k = (getCenter().sub(pixelSceneVector)).dot(getNormal()) / viewDir.dot(getNormal());

        if (k < 0) {
            return null; // Intersection behind ray origin
        }

        Vector intersection = pixelSceneVector.add(viewDir.mul(k));

        Vector ac = accessVertices(3).getPos().sub(accessVertices(1).getPos());
        Vector ab = accessVertices(2).getPos().sub(accessVertices(1).getPos());
        Vector ap = intersection.sub(accessVertices(1).getPos());

        double dotAC_AC = ac.dot(ac);
        double dotAC_AB = ac.dot(ab);
        double dotAB_AB = ab.dot(ab);
        double dotAC_AP = ac.dot(ap);
        double dotAB_AP = ab.dot(ap);

        double invDenom = 1 / (dotAC_AC * dotAB_AB - dotAC_AB * dotAC_AB);
        double u = (dotAB_AB * dotAC_AP - dotAC_AB * dotAB_AP) * invDenom;
        double v = (dotAC_AC * dotAB_AP - dotAC_AB * dotAC_AP) * invDenom;

        if (u >= 0 && v >= 0 && (u + v) <= 1) {
            // Intersection is within the triangle
            return new IntersectionInfo(intersection, getNormal());
        }

        return null; // No intersection within triangle
    }

I would attach my traversal algorithm but im almost certain its not my BVH because of some testing i ran, I attached a picture of my result,
picture with backface culling implemented
and as you can see the white gap is present, but if i remove this section of the intersect code which handles backface culling
image with no backface culling
        // Check if the triangle is facing away from the ray
        double normalDotRayDir = getNormal().dot(ray.getDirection());
        if (normalDotRayDir > 0) {
            // Triangle is facing away from the ray (backface), skip intersection
            return null;
        }

then it reappears but causes a bunch of other weird artifacts that i think tell me that i need backface culling but it isnt working and is seemingly the cause of the gap.
Trying to remove the backface culling section did remove the gap but seemingly did not fix it as it caused a bunch of other problems, i thought it might be something to do with my triangle normal calculation but i dont know how that could work everywhere but one little part if its the cause, ill attach that below here
    public Vector getNormal() {
        Vector normal = ((vertices.get(1).getPos().sub(vertices.get(0).getPos())).cross(vertices.get(2).getPos().sub(vertices.get(1).getPos())));
        return normal;
    }

I've never posted to stackoverflow before really so Im not sure what other info might be needed, but am happy to give anything you might ask for, any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.
